# Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes

Tags: android, android-webview

In system process, I need to use WebView for some purpose. However when try to inflate, the exception happens:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes

As I check the https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewFactory.java,
I check Line 189 in `getProvider()` method

```
if (uid == android.os.Process.ROOT_UID || uid == android.os.Process.SYSTEM_UID) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
"For security reasons, WebView is not allowed in privileged processes");
}
```

So I am unable to use the WebView. Any suggestions how to achieve this ?
P.S I cannot change the uid has to be system so ruled out.

Comment: Use something other than `WebView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare any alernative suggestions ?

Comment: Since I do not know what you are using `WebView` for, I have no means of making any suggestions.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Need to show Websheet to user with the User-Data stored on the Remote Server so that user can edit it to update to server. Does this bring some clarity to my requirement ?

Comment: Why is a system app doing this sort of thing? What you want sounds perfectly fine for a normal app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I need to create other app then & not use the system app. There is no way to by-pass it since Google keeps it that way. Though I am still curios for the security concern.

Comment: Web rendering engines are a constant source of security exploits. If a system app gets pwned through `WebView`, that pwnage could have serious ramifications for the user. Hence, I am not surprised that they put this block in place. Android O moves more of the Web rendering to a separate process, so it is possible that they relax this restriction in the future.